# Find which files within a directory do not contain a match to a regex string

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I thought that maybe `grep -v "<ignore file with this text>" $(ls)` might work, but it ends up returning every single line within each file that does not match the text. What I want is for the file to be ignored if it contains any number of matches. As follows

Input

```
file1<-- matches
file2
file3<-- matches
file4<-- matches
file5
```

Output

```
file2
file5
```

Comment: Don't use `ls + grep`. Use `find` with `-not -name` option or `-not -regex`

Comment: @anubhava Is there any specific reason to use `find` instead of `ls` + `grep`?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-l` (lower case L) option with `-v` invert match.

`-l, --files-with-matches`  Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have  been printed.

`grep -vl "<ignore file with this text>" $(ls)`

OR

Use the `-L` (upper case L) option

`-L, --files-without-match` Suppress  normal  output;  instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.

`grep -L "<ignore file with this text>" $(ls)`